# How to merge multidimensional with specific value

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a problem in merging two-dimensional arrays

I have three arrays with the same months

first array: (Jobseeker)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [MONTH] => 5
            [jobseeker] => 4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [MONTH] => 6
            [jobseeker] => 4
        )

)
```

second array: (company)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [MONTH] => 6
            [company] => 11
        )

)
```

third array: (jobs)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [MONTH] => 6
            [job] => 20
        )

)
```

I tried this code:

```
$total_stats = array_merge_recursive($jobseeker_stats, $company_stats, $job_stats);
```

I expect the output is:

```
Array
(
     [0] => Array
        (
            [MONTH] => 5
            [jobseeker] => 4
        )
     [1] => Array
        (
            [MONTH] => 6
            [jobseeker] => 4
            [company] => 11
            [job] => 20
        )
```

Comment: And what you have tried so far?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried, so we can see what you have a problem with. It doesn't matter if the code doesn't exactly do what you want.

Comment: sorry i edited just now

Comment: Is month unique in each array? And please replace your print_r in the question with var_export

Comment: if you are getting this info from a database, you might want to look up `join` statements, as I feel it would be a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [array_column()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php), [array_search()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) with [foreach()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

```
$seconArrayMonths =  array_column($array2,'MONTH');
$thirdArrayMonths =  array_column($array3,'MONTH');


foreach($array1 as &$arr){
    $secondArrayMonthKey = array_search($arr['MONTH'],$seconArrayMonths);
    if($secondArrayMonthKey !== false){
        $arr['company'] = $array2[$secondArrayMonthKey]['company'];
    }
    $thirdArrayMonthKey = array_search($arr['MONTH'],$thirdArrayMonths);
    if($thirdArrayMonthKey !== false){
        $arr['job'] = $array3[$secondArrayMonthKey]['job'];
    }

}

print_r($array1);
```

Output:-https://3v4l.org/BKJqj

Comment: doesn't this answer assume that the first array is always the largest? might not matter to op

Comment: @Alex  agreed, and it needs to be confirmed by the OP. Let him say something regarding this

Comment: @BossMaltik  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 1):

```
$jobSeeker = array('0' => array('MONTH' => 5,'jobseeker' => 4),'1' => array('MONTH' => 6, 'jobseeker' => 4));
$company = array('0' => array('MONTH' => 6,'company' => 11));
$jobs = array('0' => array('MONTH' => 6,'job' => 20));

$mergeArray = array();

foreach($jobSeeker as $js){
    $mergeArray[$js['MONTH']]['MONTH'] = $js['MONTH'];
    $mergeArray[$js['MONTH']]['jobseeker'] = $js['jobseeker'];
}

foreach($company as $c){
    $mergeArray[$c['MONTH']]['MONTH'] = $c['MONTH'];
    $mergeArray[$c['MONTH']]['company'] = $c['company'];
}

foreach($jobs as $j){
    $mergeArray[$j['MONTH']]['MONTH'] = $j['MONTH'];
    $mergeArray[$j['MONTH']]['job'] = $j['job'];
}

$result = array();
foreach($mergeArray as $m){ 
    array_push($result, $m);
}
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make the arrays associative and use array_replace_recursive.

```
$jobSeeker = array_column($jobSeeker, Null, "MONTH");
$company = array_column($company, Null, "MONTH");
$jobs = array_column($jobs, Null, "MONTH");

$jobSeeker = array_replace_recursive($jobSeeker, $company, $jobs);
var_dump($jobSeeker);
```

Output

```
array(2) {
  [5]=>
  array(2) {
    ["MONTH"]=>
    int(5)
    ["jobseeker"]=>
    int(4)
  }
  [6]=>
  array(4) {
    ["MONTH"]=>
    int(6)
    ["jobseeker"]=>
    int(4)
    ["company"]=>
    int(11)
    ["job"]=>
    int(20)
  }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/HW7OV